# Distribution of inbag matrix when sampling with replacement

Tags: probability, sampling, bootstrap, density-function

Say I take a random sample of size $M$ from a sample of size $N$, like, for example you'd do when bootstrapping in random forest.

As you increase $M$, you're more likely to sample any particular observation an increasing number of times.

When $M = N$, it's been shown that you get zero instances of any given element about .38 percent of the time.

I want to know what this distribution of the inbag matrix is -- the distribution of counts over elements -- as $M$ is varied.

To see random draws of this distribution for $N = 26$ and $M = 10$, you can run this a bunch of times:

```
data.frame(table(table(sample(letters[1:26], 10, replace = T))))
```

I'm looking for an analytical function to give me the expectation of how many times ecah inbag count will show up as a function of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05822.pdf?

Comment: @user2974951 sort of.  I could probably use the results in that paper to get what I want, which is the distribution over the number of times each element is sampled given N and M.  But reading that paper is edifying at minimum because it confirms that the problem is hard.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the **classical occupancy problem** which leads to the classical occupancy distribution.  Let $1 \leqslant K \leqslant \min(M,N)$ denote the number of different values that are resampled.  Then the probability mass function for this random variable is the classical occupancy distribution:

$$\mathbb{P}(K=k) = \frac{(N)_k \cdot S(M,k)}{N^M}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } 1 \leqslant k \leqslant \min(M,N),$$

where $(N)_k = N(N-1)(N-2) \cdots (N-k+1)$ are the [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) and $S(M,k)$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  Letting $E_r \equiv (1-r/N)^M$, the mean and variance of the distribution are:

$$\mathbb{E}(K) = N (1-E_1)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\mathbb{V}(K) = N [(N-1) E_2 + E_1 - N \cdot E_1^2].$$

The properties of this distribution and methods for its computation are well-known (for details on the properties and computation of this distribution, see e.g. [O'Neill 2020](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2019.1699445)).  For large values of $M$ and $N$ you can approximate it well by a normal distribution with identical mean and variance.